# How to make HashMap key return JSON format output?

Tags: java, json

I'm very sorry if the title is a little misleading... I really don't know what is exactly the terms but don't worry I have provided my code just in case.

I have a JSON string called `json_string`, this is its value:

```
{
  "record": {
    "sample": "Hello World",
    "sample_2": "Hello World_2"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "id": "value",
    "private": "true"
  }
}
```

I can convert this JSON string to HashMap using this line of code:

```
myHashMap = new Gson().fromJson(json_string, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
```

Now I can get the contents of the key `record` and pass it to string called `final_output` using this code:

```
String final_output = myHashMap.get("record").toString();
```

the string `final_output` is:

```
{ sample=Hello World, sample_2=Hello World_2 }
```

How can I make it return this format again:

```
{
"sample": "Hello World",
"sample_2": "Hello World_2"
}
```

?

Thanks for answering

Comment: At some point you must have removed the formatting whitespace. `HashMap` doesn't do that.

Comment: Uhhm, doesn't do what exactly?

Comment: All inputs are response from the api i use so there's no way i must have removed anything

Comment: Any alternatives on how can i achieve my desired mentioned format above when getting the record key?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that `new Gson().fromJson()` removed it? And why do you think you need the formatting? Gson doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

GSON has a built-in method for pretty printing

```
.setPrettyPrinting()
```

To enable Gson pretty print, you must configure the Gson instance using the ***setPrettyPrinting()*** method of GsonBuilder class and this method configures Gson to output JSON that fits in a page for pretty printing.

**For your case:**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create(); 
myhashmap = gson.fromJson(json_string, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
```

**Update:**

You can get the prettified json Object from a key as a String. (here 'record')

```
String output = gson.toJson(myHashMap.get("record")).toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this example helps you:

```
SortedMap<String, String> elements = new TreeMap();
elements.put("Key1", "Value1");
elements.put("Key2", "Value2");
elements.put("Key3", "Value3");

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type gsonType = new TypeToken<HashMap>(){}.getType();
String gsonString = gson.toJson(elements,gsonType);
System.out.println(gsonString);
```

Output:

```
{"Key1":"Value1","Key2":"Value2","Key3":"Value3"}
```

For  your case:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type gsonType = new TypeToken<HashMap>(){}.getType();
String final_output = gson.toJson(myHashMap.get("record"),gsonType);
System.out.println(final_output);
```

Comment: That's exactly what he said he didn't want.